# Is it possible to enumerate cells in a table?

Tags: tables, numbering

I would like to enumerate cells in a table using the following scheme :

```
1.     4.     7.
2.     5.     8.
3.     6.     9.
```

The problem is that I don't know the number of rows in my table.

Of course, if I write something like :

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \newcounter{cellnum}
    \newcommand{\itemtab}{\stepcounter{cellnum}\thecellnum.}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{lll}
        \itemtab & \itemtab & \itemtab \\
        \itemtab & \itemtab & \itemtab \\
        \itemtab & \itemtab & \itemtab \\
    \end{tabular}
    \end{document}
```

I get the transposed result where the cell at the first row and second column get the number `2.`

So is there a way enumerate cells using a columns first scheme ? Or is there a way to get at the very beginning of a table the number of rows it will have ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to declare the row number at the beginning for each table. We make a wrapper environment for this that takes two arguments - the row number, and the column specification. We also define some column types that create the cell numbers for us - F for the first column, G for all others.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{calc,array}
\newcounter{rownum}
\newcounter{colnum}
\newcounter{totalrows}
\newcounter{cellnum}

\newcommand{\cell}{\stepcounter{colnum}\setcounter{cellnum}{\thecolnum*\thetotalrows+\therownum+1}\thecellnum. }
\newcommand{\firstcell}{\stepcounter{rownum}\setcounter{colnum}{-1}\cell}

\newcolumntype{F}{>{\firstcell}l}
\newcolumntype{G}{>{\cell}l}

\newenvironment{numberedtabular}[2]{%
\setcounter{totalrows}{#1}%
\setcounter{rownum}{-1}%
\setcounter{colnum}{-1}%
\begin{tabular}{#2}}
%
{\end{tabular}}


\begin{document}

Here comes the first table. 

\begin{numberedtabular}{3}{FGG}
    a & b & c \\
    d & e & f \\
    g & h & i \\
\end{numberedtabular}

Here comes the second table.

\begin{numberedtabular}{2}{FGG}
    a & b & c \\
    d & e & f \\
\end{numberedtabular}

And here comes the third.

\begin{numberedtabular}{4}{FGG}
    a & b & c \\
    d & e & f \\
    g & h & i \\
    j & l & m \\
\end{numberedtabular}

\end{document}
```

This gives:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It works. I wait a bit just to see if there is an answer which does not need me to declare the total number of rows.

Comment: The problem is that the cell numbers in the first row depend on the total number of rows. If you want to avoid declaring the row number, you must find a way to save the entire table first before starting to typeset it. There is package `tabularx`, which reprocesses each table implicitly, and maybe you can somehow adapt that to your needs. Seems more trouble than it's worth to me though.

Comment: You could use the aux file to save the dimensions of the table.

Comment: I tried to see in the tabularx documentation if there is some command for the number of rows but I don't think there is. I will try to use the aux file as suggested by @dexteritas, so that I can use your code.

Comment: @dexteritas - good suggestion. I used it.

Comment: To use this with more than one table you'll need to generate a new total rows counter for each table.

Comment: Thanks for the edit with the aux file. The thing is, I have plenty of such tables, and not all of them have the same number of rows... This is why I was looking at a way to make it automatically.

Comment: @Roland - see updated answer. You can simply declare the row number separately for each table.

Comment: Ok I think I prefer the solution with the auxiliary file. But thanks for all your tips, they were very helpful !

Comment: The problem with the aux file solution is that it does not handle the case with multiple tables. The current solution does.

Comment: @Roland I've added an answer with a version of the `.aux` file solution that handles multiple tables.

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't use any borders of the table in your example you could also use `multicols` with `enumerate`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{3}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item a
    \item b
    \item c
    \item d
    \item e
    \item f
    \item g
    \item h
    \item i
    \end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I may use something like it if I don't have a solution. The thing is, I would prefer an alignment between the rows. For example, if the cell 1 is long, then with your solution 2 will be lower than 5.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a version of Michael Palmer's second (now deleted) answer using the `.aux` file to store the total rows for each table. This eliminates the need for specifying the total rows for each table, and handles as many enumerated tables in the document as you like. I've made most of the commands internal (containing `@`) so that the counters used are less likely to interfere with any user defined counters.

I've made the environment as a wrapper around a standard `tabular` environment, but the environment can be rewritten to include the `tabular` by making it take an argument to pass to a `\begin{tabular}` within the environment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{calc,array}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{row@num}
\newcounter{col@num}
\newcounter{total@rows}
\newcounter{cell@num}
\newcounter{enumtbl@cnt}

\newcommand*{\@resettablcounters}{
\setcounter{row@num}{-1}
\setcounter{cell@num}{-1}
\setcounter{col@num}{-1}
}

\newcommand{\cell}{%
    \stepcounter{col@num}
    \setcounter{cell@num}
        {\value{col@num}*\value{total@rows}+\value{row@num}+1}%
        \thecell@num. }
\newcommand{\firstcell}
    {\stepcounter{row@num}\setcounter{col@num}{-1}\cell}

\newcolumntype{F}{>{\firstcell}l}
\newcolumntype{G}{>{\cell}l}

\newenvironment{enumtabular}
    {\@resettablcounters
     \stepcounter{enumtbl@cnt}
     \xdef\@tabnum{enumtab\roman{enumtbl@cnt}}
     \setcounter{total@rows}{\numexpr\csuse{\@tabnum}+1}    
    }
    {\immediate\write\@auxout{\csgdef{\@tabnum}{\therow@num}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{enumtabular}
\begin{tabular}{FGG}
    a & b & c \\
    d & e & f \\
    g & h & i 
\end{tabular}
\end{enumtabular}
\bigskip

\begin{enumtabular}
\begin{tabular}{FGG}
    a & b & c \\
    d & e & f \\
    g & h & i \\
    j & k & l \\
    m & n & o
\end{tabular}
\end{enumtabular}
\bigskip

\begin{enumtabular}
\begin{tabular}{FGG}
    a & b & c \\
    d & e & f \\
    g & h & i \\
    j & k & l\\
    m & n & o\\
    p & q & r\\
    s & t & u
\end{tabular}
\end{enumtabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Excellent. I tried but failed to come up with something like this. It's the `\numexpr\csuse` cruft that was a little beyond me ;)

Comment: @MichaelPalmer Yes, the tricky thing here is (i) to avoid creating a new counter for each table (bad idea!) and instead generating a unique macro name off of a single counter (ii) "freezing" the counter number when creating the macro that stores the total row number. `etoolbox` makes doing some of this stuff a lot easier.

Comment: @AlanMunn - thanks for the added explanation.